# Android Security - Cryptography to store sensitive information using pin

Tags: android, security, android-security

In my app, I am saving some data in shared preference which has to be encrypted before saving and has to be decrypted when retrieving.

I am using AES-256 encryption. For that, I am generating the secret key using a passphrase/pin. Below is my code snippet.

```
    public static SecretKey generateKey(char[] passphraseOrPin, byte[] salt) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {
    // Number of PBKDF2 hardening rounds to use. Larger values increase
    // computation time. You should select a value that causes computation
    // to take >100ms.
    final int iterations = 1000; 

    // Generate a 256-bit key
    final int outputKeyLength = 256;

    SecretKeyFactory secretKeyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
    KeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(passphraseOrPin, salt, iterations, outputKeyLength);
    SecretKey secretKey = secretKeyFactory.generateSecret(keySpec);
    return secretKey;
}
```

As per my app, I  can ask the user to provide a unique pin. But I am not able to save the pin in keystore, because the app has to support from 4.0. How can I save the pin?

Answer (score 0):

For this, I would recommend you look into using Facebook Conceal library. It is compatible with android up to API 9 as per their `build.gradle`: https://github.com/facebook/conceal/blob/master/build.gradle

You can follow their guidance on the website here on how to integrate:

https://github.com/facebook/conceal

Answer (score 0):

Use the [KeyChain](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/KeyChain.html) instead. It is compatible down to API 14 (ICS). The main difference being that the KeyChain is available systemwide.

However, I wonder, why are you storing the pin? Keys protected by passwords exist to prevent unauthorized use, so usage should be authorized by the user by entering his/her password.